# Cant iterate over generator object created by scan

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use the elasticsearch helpers function scan but although its generating an object

```
q = {"query": {"match": {"name": 'AAPL'}}}
quot = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(self.es, query=q, index=self.esindex, doc_type="stock")
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f121c089750>
```

when I try to get its content something is wrong. My code is a simple

```
for val in quot
    print(val)
list(gen)
```

But when I debug the code directly jumps off the loop and shows [] as output of the list()

If I try to do

```
next(quot)
```

I get: StopIteration so seems to me something is wrong with the object.

Do you know what could be going wrong? Is there any other easy way to do what scan does?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your query actually returns some data?

Comment: yes, cause if I do the same query outside python with curl I get data

Comment: if you deque it, you can see any content?

    from collections import deque
    quot = deque(elasticsearch.helpers.scan(self.es, query=q, index=self.esindex, doc_type="stock"))

Comment: Doing deque actually made me realize that solution was simpler. doc_type arg is mandatory in early versions of elasticsearch but no longer on new ones. As I tried to execute the code in a new instance version was new. Removing the doc_type arg made it work flawless. Thanks